# Using wp_get_archives to only show months of posts with particular meta key?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently working on a project that has us using Advanced Custom Fields to separate Posts between Customer or Employee posts.

On the sidebar of each respective blog type, I was hoping to show the months in which posts were created for either Employee or Customer by use of the meta key/meta value.

I was able to successfully use this method for showing Recent Posts with wp_get_recent_posts() by using the meta_key/meta_value arguments:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => '4',
            'meta_key' => 'blog_type',
            'meta_value' => 'Customer Blog'
        ));
```

Sadly wp_get_archives does not allow these arguments. Is there a way to get the desired effect? Current setup shows posts created for all types.

```
            wp_get_archives(array(
            'format' => 'custom',
            'before' => ' <div class="post-list"><div class="text-1-1 fontawesome5free-solid-normal-grenadier-20px"></div> <div class="january-2021 small-paragraph">',
            'after' => '</div></div>',
            'limit' => 4,
        ));
```

Comment: `wp_get_archives` executes filters such as `getarchives_where` and `getarchives_join`, so it would probably be doable using those ...

Comment: after reviewing some other answers, this does seem to be the right direction, I just don't seem to know exactly how to code it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way and also you can modify date_query according to yours

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'numberposts' => '4',
            'meta_key' => 'blog_type',
            'meta_value' => 'Customer Blog'
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                   'year'  => date('Y'),
                    'month' => date('m'),
                    'day'   => date('d'),
               ),
            ),
        ));
```